# python Run for loop on two variables and passing the variable as rsync destination

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, rsync

The code below runs well to synchronize two directories concurrently when done in bash; However, it is proving difficult to do the same in python.
I am going to show both attempts and you give me your feedback
bash

```
#!/bin/bash
for dest in /backup1 /backup2 /backup3; do
rsync -aviS /source $dest
done
```

In python, i tried this to no avail.I want to do the same as above but in python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
def func_sync():

dest1 = '/home/user/test/new_test1/'
dest2 = '/home/user/test/new_test2/'
zipped = zip(dest1,dest2)
sync = os.system("rsync -av '/home/user/Documents/testsync_p/' \(for data in zipped)")
return sync

func_sync()
```

How can i refine this?

Answer (score 0):

This sorts out the problem above. Make use of the shutil module.

```
    import shutil
    src = "/home/user/Documents/src_dir"
    dst = ("/home/user/Documents/dst_1", "/home/user/Documents/dst_2")
    for i in dst:
        shutil.copytree(src, i)
```